# Не могу обратиться к полю в class

Tags: c++

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int points = 0;
    string answer = "";
};
MyClass c;
c.answer = "string";
```

После компилиции выдает ошибку "Это объявление не содержит класс хранения или спецификатор типа"

Comment: Извините не struct а class

Comment: `#include <string>` есть в коде? И `std::string` должно быть, или `using namespace std;` на худой конец.

Comment: Да, там если к полю int таже ошибка..

Comment: [Всё работает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MVUZ6KL9stf2PptI). Приведите [mcve]. Может быть вы на глобальном уровне пытаетесь это вызвать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо вызвать из функции или метода